Growth of preimages of singular values of finite type entire map
Let $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire map having precisely two distinct singular values $w^1$ and $w^2$. If $w^i$ has infinitely many preimages under $f$, we write $(z_n^i)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := f^{-1}(w^i)$, where we order points of the preimage so that the sequence $(|z_n^i|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of absolute values is non-decreasing, i.e., $|z_{n + 1}^i| \geq |z_{n}^i|$ (and, of course, we suppose that they are all distinct: $z_n^i \neq z_m^i$ for $n \neq m$).
I am curious about various growth properties of the sequence $(z_n^i)$. In particular, I wonder if there exists $A > 0$ (depending on $f$) so that for $i = 1$ or $i = 2$ we have
$$
\frac{\log|z_{n + 1}^i|}{\log|z_{n}^i|} \leq A.
$$
Or, perhaps, there is a counterexample? And if it is so, then what conditions $f$ should satisfy so such constant $A$ exists? And of course, this question makes sense for any finite number of singular values...

At least a variant of your statement is true, see Lemma 3.2 in my paper with Miriam Benini. Let $f$ is a transcendental entire function that is bounded on an unbounded connected set. (This is always true when the set of singular values is bounded.) Let $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, for all $C>1$, and all sufficiently large $R$, the annulus between moduli $R/C$ and $C\cdot R$ contains a point of $f^{-1}(z_1,z_2)$. This means that, if you enumerate ALL preimages of $f^{-1}(z_1,z_2)$, and consider the analogue of the quotient of logarithms in your statement, then this quotient tends to one.
I think that it is not true that either one of the two singular values itself must have such a sequence of preimages. Indeed, you can fairly easily build a function that omits 0 in some large annulus, then omits 1 in another, even larger annulus, etc.
The proof of the lemma above is simple and uses Montel's theorem. Suppose that the negation holds, then there exists a sequence of round annuli of definite modulus, centred at zero, on which the function omits $z_1$ and $z_2$. Rescaling by $R$, we obtain a normal family by Montel's theorem. Any limit function must be holomorphic by the assumption on $f$ and Hurwitz's theorem, since there is a point on the central curve of the annuli in question on which the function stays bounded. But this means that our sequence of functions remains bounded on this central curve; i.e., the original $f$ remains bounded on a sequence of concentric circles whose radii tend to infinity. Clearly this is impossible for a non-constant entire function.
